# wordpress - multiple get_option of category returning same result

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, posts

I have 2 blocks of code both trying to pull a single post from from different categories respectively but they are both returning the same post - the content of the second one to be exact.  Here is my code...

```
      <!-- homepage block 1 - START -->
  <? $homepage = get_option('of_homepage') ?>
  <?php query_posts('category_name='.$homepage.'&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <!-- Add your content here -->

  <div id="m2" class="f-ms">
    <div id="m3" class="f-ms">
      <h3 class="subtitlessmaller f-fp f-lp">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="m4" class="f-ms">
      <p class="whitewider f-fp">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile;?>
  <!-- homepage block 1 - END --> 

      <!-- homepage block 2 - START --> 
    <? $homepage2 = get_option('of_homepage2') ?>
    <?php query_posts('category_name='.$homepage2.'&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Add your content here -->

    <div id="featboxtitle" class="f-ms">
      <p class="f-fp f-lp"><span class="subindex"><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
    </div>
    <div id="featimage" class="f-ms">
      <p class="f-fp f-lp"><?php the_post_thumbnail(''); ?></p>
    </div>
    <p class="smaller">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <!-- homepage block 2 - END -->
```

I am completely new to Wordpress so forgive me if what I am trying to do is not possible

Answer (score 0):

i found my own solution. I needed to asign a category to each post in the theme-options.php file and then select them from the theme options in the admin panel like so...

```
//Select Category
$options[] = array( "name" => "Select a Category for the first homepage greeting",
                "desc" => "Hit the dropdown and select a category from the listings",
                "id" => $shortname."_homepage",
                "std" => "Select a category:",
                "type" => "select",
                "options" => $of_categories);  

//Select Category
$options[] = array( "name" => "Select a Category for the second homepage block of text",
                "desc" => "Hit the dropdown and select a category from the listings",
                "id" => $shortname."_homepage2",
                "std" => "Select a category:",
                "type" => "select",
                "options" => $of_categories);
```

Comment: I'd like to congratulate myself on being such a good help to myself today :-)